# "Index was outside the bounds of the array" while Compare SQL schema by SQL compare tool

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I got one problem from comparing database schema as i use Red gate SQL Compare 6 , after initialization of the compare databases error is coming as following

```
"Index was outside the bounds of the array".
```

Please provide your valuable comments to get resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried upgrading? The latest version released is [8.1](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm), and your issue might have been fixed in the intervening versions. You can also try posting on their [support forums](http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/)...

Comment: Thanks, i have contacted with Support team of red gate, they have upgraded our serial number and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use version 6 on 64 bit versions of SQL Server...](http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/viewtopic.php?t=7550&highlight=index+outside+bounds+array&sid=2ac25c2b3916a634b02f8729a11f1714) [Or 7](http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/viewtopic.php?t=7900&highlight=index+outside+bounds+array&sid=2ac25c2b3916a634b02f8729a11f1714), it appears.

- The computer running SQL Compare is using a 64-bit edition of Windows
- One or more of the servers being compared are SQL Server 2005 or higher
- The Decrypt encryped objects on SQL 2005 and 2008 databases option is selected

I've been using Redgate stuff since 2003 and don't remember this error.

I really would consider upgrading...

Answer (score 0):

Try [dbForge Scheme Compare for SQL server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/schemacompare/). It can compare and synchronize any database scheme. Quick, easy, always delivering a correct result. See how it flies on your database!